# Discord.py read json data print and if statement

Tags: python, json, if-statement, discord.py

My admins.json

```
{
  "admins": [
    {
      "admin_name": "admin#5123",
      "admin_id": "1024561820381491231"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
f = open('admins.json')
data = json.load(f)

for i in data['admins']:
    print(i)
```

how to check if the memberid from message author in admins.json?

i was trying to do `if ctx.author.id in admins.json` but its not working can you guys help me (:

i was trying to google or read the docs from JSON Python or discord.py but its noting no find

Comment: Do you want to check if the user is admin?

Comment: if the id in the file same as the user id

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the below

```
admins = {
    "admins": [
        {
            "admin_name": "admin#5123",
            "admin_id": "1024561820381491231"
        },
        {
            "admin_name": "admin#5123",
            "admin_id": "102456182038184633"
        }
    ]
}


def is_admin(member_id: str) -> bool:
    for admin in admins['admins']:
        if admin['admin_id'] == member_id:
            return True
    return False


print(is_admin('102456182038184633'))
```